# How to run a query with date from a form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-query

I have a select query that returns records based on 2 dates from a form - `>=Forms!frmReport!StartDate AND <=Forms!frmReport!EndDate`. 
The problem is that whenever the user enters the same date in the both `StartDate` and `EndDate` no record is returned even though I'm sure there is data in the table that matches the criteria. Can anyone say why the query isn't returning any information?

Comment: It is conceivable that the criteria would not return an existing record if that record included a time.  For today, the date criteria might be <= 41757 AND >= 41757 and the record contains 41757.63875.  Same day but outside the criteria.

Comment: the default for the field when capturing the data is set to `=Now()` so the field includes a time. Just now I realize that if i remove the time from the associated field in the table then the information comes up. Does that mean that i would have to capture Date and Time separately?

Comment: Is time relevant? If so, we'll need to craft the criteria differently.  If it is not, see Yawar's comment below.

Comment: yes the time is relevant. geoB's method worked perfectly except it just dropped of the time.

Answer (score 1):

If the field being compared is `rs("Date")`, try

```
Int(rs("Date")) >=Forms!frmReport!StartDate AND Int(rs("Date")) <=Forms!frmReport!EndDate
```

For the Query Builder, modify your date checking field to something like this:

[image]

Replace `YourDateField` with the name of your field.

And if time is relevant, get rid of the field expression in the query builder, and instead compare the record's field to:

```
>=Forms!frmReport!StartDate AND <= iif(Forms!frmReport!EndDate = Forms!frmReport!StartDate, dateadd("d",1,Forms!frmReport!EndDate), Forms!frmReport!EndDate)
```

This expression says if the end date is the same as the start date add a day, otherwise just use the end date.

Comment: I could not get this to work in the query builder. Am I putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: the query now works well. It returns the date only and leaves off the attached time. but i guest i will have to store the time in a field of its own.

Comment: No need to add a field.  Try the extra-long expression in the edited solution.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the form values to *just* date values in your query:

```
>= cdate(Forms![frmReport]![StartDate]) and <= cdate(Forms![frmReport]![EndDate])
```

And set your field default to `=date()` to capture the date only, instead of `=now()`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion with the cdate but it didn't return any result. even after i changed the default to `Date()` the existing data already had the time attached.